# Dash, Plotly, Python, Syntax error on the definition of the function get graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to debug this code in Dash, basically I am trying to define a function that gets the graphs to display, after the callback decorator, so the problem seems to be that I can't figure out how to do that. for some reason I get a SYNTAX error. Here is the code, see if you can help.

```
@app.callback( [Output(component_id='plot1', component_property='children'),
 Output(component_id='plot2', component_property='children'),
 Output(component_id='plot3', component_property='children'),
 Output(component_id='plot4', component_property='children'),
 Output(component_id='plot5', component_property='children')],
            [Input(component_id='input-type', component_property='value'),
                Input(component_id='input-year', component_property='value')],
               # REVIEW4: Holding output state till user enters all the form information. In this case, it will be chart type and year
               [State("plot1", 'children'), State("plot2", "children"),
                State("plot3", "children"), State("plot4", "children"),
                State("plot5", "children")
               ])
# Add computation to callback function and return graph
def get_graph(chart, year, children1, children2, c3, c4, c5):
```

[image: Syntax ERRROR]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try using a text editor to check that the brackets match up the way you expect them to? Did you try using a text editor to make sure that tabs and spaces are used consistently? When I copy and paste your code (and add a `pass` for the body of the method), I do not get a syntax error. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to diagnose the problem yourself first before posting here.

Comment: Also: like it says when you hover over the `hyphen` tag - don't use it for questions about Dash. Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and try to ask questions explicitly in the future. Finally: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). If you have an error message to show, then copy and paste the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message (starting with the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` and format it as code.

Comment: I second @KarlKnechtel's comment. I did the exact same thing by adding `pass` for the body of the `get_graph` method and cannot reproduce the syntax error you're getting